# How to see how long a document has until disposition?

Tags: sharepoint-online, retention, records-management, records-center, record

I'm new to the Sharepoint Records Management space (e5 licence). I'm using a test environment to play around and figure out how things work and what they'll look like for my team. I've made some record labels with event based retention periods, applied these labels to some documents, and then created the event. I'm fairly confident I've done all of these steps right, but to check, I am hoping to be able to see how long the documents I've applied this retention label and event to have before disposition.

Is there a way to do this? The Data Classification overview is showing no retention labels have been applied. I've clicked around, clicked on the document that I've applied the record to and can't find a way to access this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Go to Microsoft 365 admin center -> Security -> Information governance -> Retention -> Check the retention policy.

2.Go to the classic library where the document stores -> Click Ellipsis -> Advanced -> Compliance Details -> Check the retention policy.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have worked. Unofrtunately either I've done something wrong setting the event trigger or something else is going on as its saying the document is not subject to a retention policy. The fun of SharePoint!